# How to search highlighted data in the site?

Tags: search, blogger

I am using Blogger to record my thoughts. I have inserted search box to search my thinking; I have highlighted important thoughts using the highlighter; as I want to explore more only on those important thoughts, I want a way to bring them together. Is there a way to find only those highlighted text in a page, or find them using HTML code of the highlighting color--a search engine for finding HTML? Or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

There's really no way to search for highlighted text, unless you want to search through the source code for the HTML tags.  A better bet may be to use Blogger's ***labels***.

The labels are just like tags or keywords; you can use them to organize your posts.  For example, you could label posts that you want to come back to with "important," "check," etc.

To make it even easier, you could add the Labels gadget to your blog, in the sidebar or at the top or bottom.  The Labels gadget shows all your labels, in the format you select, and you can click on one to show all the posts with that label.

Answer (score 1):

*(Originally included in question)*

I have now inserted unique symbol before every highlighted content. If I type that unique symbol in the search box, it is presenting me all the highlighted content! But, I need to insert special symbol every time I highlight content.